# HTML file upload not sending files to $_FILES

Tags: php, forms, file-upload

I have an html form and when the user chooses a file and submits it the $_FILES in the php document doesn't receive the it.  The main focus is the form, when I hit submit no file gets submitted but the onclick event fires.  and there are no error messages

```
    <form id="artist_post" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" onsubmit="return " action="php_parsers/newsfeed_system.php">
<textarea id="statustext" onkeyup="statusMax(this,250)"></textarea>
<input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="30000" />
<input id="audioUpload" type="file" name="audioUpload" accept="audio/*" />
<input type="submit" value="Post" id="statusBtn" onclick="postToStatus('status_post','a','statustext')"/>
</form>
```

Here is the php doc, I'm just trying to see if the file is getting uploaded

```
    if (isset($_FILES["audioUpload"]["name"])) {
        echo "flag1";
    }
    if ($_FILES["audioUpload"]["tmp_name"] != "") {
        echo "flag2";
    }
```

The javascript takes the information from the form and sends it to php through ajax.

```
function postToStatus(action,type,ta){
var data = _(ta).value;
if(data == ""){
    alert("Type something first");
    return false;
}

// Checks to see if user uploaded a file to send with post 
if(_("audioUpload").value != "") { 
    type = "c";
}   

_("statusBtn").disabled = true;
var ajax = ajaxObj("POST", "php_parsers/newsfeed_system.php");
ajax.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if(ajaxReturn(ajax) == true) {
        //Pull some info from whatever the php doc returns
    }
}

ajax.send("action="+action+"&type="+type+"&data="+data);
}
function ajaxObj(meth, url) {
var x = new XMLHttpRequest();  // create new http request 
x.open( meth, url, true );  // open request and pass it a method and a url to post it to 
x.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"); 
return x;
}
// Modular function that externalizes readyState and status check
function ajaxReturn(x) {
if(x.readyState == 4 && x.status == 200) {
    return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: what does your javascript `postToStatus()` function contain?

Comment: First take out `onsubmit="return "` and `onclick="postToStatus()"` unless you make a proper call to that/those functions.

Comment: are you trying to post files trough javascript? cuz that won't work without jquery lib

Comment: @JerkoW.Tisler "without the jquery lib"; you do know that jquery is written *in* javascript right and that everything that you can do with jquery you can, consequently, do without it (in raw javascript)?

Comment: Yeah ofc you can do it in JS. I mean yeah you are right JQuery is written in javascript but honestly i really doubt that you wrote 1000+ lines of code to upload file with native JS

Comment: sorry i meant through AJAX not through raw javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `<form action="...">` needs to be removed.  You are using AJAX and are therefore bypassing the form action sequence all together.  I have created a replica of this on my server and it works without that there.

I would recommend throwing it into a JSFiddle now and again and hitting the "Tidy" button up top.  Otherwise, well done on the code so far.

In case you wanted to see my duplicate copy in action:  [click here](http://1054.fleeceitout.com/sweet.php)

Comment: When I take out the '<form action="...">' it still isnt sending the file to the php doc.  I agree and appreciate your input, I was thinking that it wasnt working because of my bypass using ajax.  However I cant seem to figure out why the file wont send.  Javascript cant read the file, which is how I originally had it coded.  Any other suggestions?